# How can I use different PHP-FPM pools for different PHP's with Nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

The directory structure looks like this:

```
/home/test/index.php
/home/test/stats.php
/home/test/contact.php
```

When I call the URL: [testsite.com/stats.php](http://testsite.com/stats.php)
 
I want to use the pool [back] but all other PHP's (index.php, contact.php) should use the pool [front].

/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/back.conf

```
[back]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
listen.backlog = 4096
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.mode = 0660
; --------- ondemand ---------
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 50
pm.max_requests = 500
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s

pm.status_path = /backstatus
```

/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/front.conf

```
[front]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.backlog = 4096
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.mode = 0660
; --------- static ---------
pm = static
pm.max_children = 5

pm.status_path = /frontstatus
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name testsite.com; 

    access_log off;     
    log_not_found off;      
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    root /home/test;

    index index.php index.html;     

    location ~ ^/back(status|ping)$ {
            access_log off;             
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            allow xx.xxx.xxx.xx; # own IP
            deny all;

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
    }

    location ~ ^/front(status|ping)$ {
            access_log off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            allow xx.xxx.xxx.xx; # own IP
            deny all;

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }   

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as 
    # .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }    
}
```

When I open the URL: [testsite.com/frontstatus?html](http://testsite.com/frontstatus?html)
 
I see that I am using the pool [front] because the process manager is static.

When I open the URL: [testsite.com/backstatus?html](http://testsite.com/backstatus?html)
 
I see that I am using the pool [back] because the process manager is ondemand.

What should the location block look like, that the pool [back] is taken at stats.php and the pool [front] at all others ??

```
testsite.com/frontstatus?html 
testsite.com/frontping
```

use this location:

```
location ~ ^/front(status|ping)$ {
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

that's correct and

```
testsite.com/backstatus?html
testsite.com/backping
```

use this location:

```
location ~ ^/back(status|ping)$ {
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
}
```

that is correkt too.

But

```
testsite.com/index.php 
testsite.com/contact.php 
testsite.com/stats.php
```

use all the same location:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

thats wrong ... only the

```
testsite.com/stats.php
```

should use the the location with the fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;

all other PHP's should use the location with the fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

How must i write this locations?

```
location = /stats.php {
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
}
```

it does not work

Comment: Is SELinux enabled on your server? It could be a SELinux problem, why you don't use sockets instead of TCP/IP if your php-fpm backend is on the same server as nginx?

Comment: No SELinux is not installed on the server. Yes, everything is on the same server and I would like to use the whole thing as a frontend / backend so the different pools. I use TCP / IP instead of sockets because the right server for which I try this on this test server died with sockets when the traffic increases.

Comment: I edited my question again in the hope that it is now easier to understand.

Comment: I don't see any errors in your last location.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put this block

```
location = /stats.php {
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
}
```

before this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

and also before this:

```
location ~ ^/back(status|ping)$ {
        access_log off;             
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::1;
        allow xx.xxx.xxx.xx; # own IP
        deny all;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
}
```

but nothing works :(

Once I add this location:

```
location = /stats.php {
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
}
```

All PHP's use this location with the fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001, which should not be so.

What can I do so that only the stats.php uses the fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001 instead of the fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000 ??